# Адаптация европейских сказок

Tags: литература

Скажите, пожалуйста, правду ли говорят о том, что первые варианты той же "Золушки" или "Красной Шапочки" (народные, которые обработали Шарль Перро и братья Гримм) были совершенно неудобочитаемые для современного ребенка и изобиловали кровавыми подробностями?

Answer (score 3):

Я недавно только читала статью на эту тему. Не знаю, какими материалами пользовался автор при ее написании, но там действительно фигурировала масса жутких подробностей. Например, Золушкины сестры отрубали себе пальцы на ногах, чтобы туфелька подошла и др.
   Насчет "Красной шапочки".  Варианты точно наблюдаются. У меня есть книга Ш. Перро, где эта сказка заканчивается съедением девочки. 
   И в наших народных сказках тоже не все гладко. В одном сборнике попалась сказка "Заячья избушка", она же "Лиса и Заяц", где Петух в финале все-таки применяет косу для расправы с захватчицей. Остальные сказки традиционны, картинки чудесные. Но ребенку читаю без этой подробности.

Comment: Нашла эту статью, мне она показалась интересной http://davidaidelman.livejournal.com/1665627.html

Comment: >Например, Золушкины сестры отрубали себе пальцы на ногах, чтобы туфелька подошла

На что только не пойдёт женщина, чтобы выйти замуж за принца! :-)

Некоторые современные женщины под нож пластического хирурга ложатся.

Answer (score 2):

> были совершенно неудобочитаемые для современного ребенка и изобиловали кровавыми подробностями?

Да. Этот факт в общем-то известен. Более того, сами авторы часто не предназначали свои произведения детской аудитории. В той же Красной Шапочке чувствуется явный сексуальный подтекст даже в переводе. Насколько знаю, Волк бабушку не глотал, а ограничивался насилием над Шапочкой.

Но надо сказать, что и при переводе добавлено немало ляпов не для детских умов. Насчет пальцев не знаю, но какому умнику пришло в голову нарядить Золушку в совершенно нефункциональные хрустальные туфельки - это надо еще подумать. На самом деле там были башмачки из беличьего меха, белка - символ знатности рода. По-французски эти слова несколько похожи, возникла путаница, узаконенная столетиями.

Братьям Гримм, а особенно - Гауфу источником служили совершенно недетские страшилки, но к их чести эти авторы все-таки задумывались над адаптацией.
К сожалению, я не владею немецким в должной мере, а французским - вообще никак, поэтому не имея перед глазами первоисточника не буду множить слухи.

Comment: >какому умнику пришло в голову нарядить Золушку в совершенно нефункциональные хрустальные туфельки - это надо еще подумать. На самом деле там были башмачки их беличьего меха, белка - символ знатности рода. По-французски эти слова несколько похожи, возникла путаница, узаконенная столетиями.

Читал об этом. А в Золушке братьев Гримм "туфельки были из чистого золота".

Comment: Я даже боюсь представить, каково в них было танцевать и как она себе натерла ноги))))))

Comment: Большое всем спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

> были совершенно неудобочитаемые для современного ребенка и изобиловали кровавыми подробностями?

Страшноватые моменты есть. **Надюшка** в своём ответе уже указала некоторые. Но я, например, в детстве читал -- и ничего, не очень это меня пугало. Дети любят иногда что-то такое, вроде страшилок. И всё равно сами друг другу их рассказывают.

*В чёрной-чёрной комнате, где все вещи были чёрными-пречёрными, стоял чёрный человек (ужас-ужас!). И вдруг он говорит!! "Никогда! Никогда больше не буду сам перезаправлять порошком лазерный принтер!"*

Comment: У меня есть книга сказок братьев Гримм, изданная ещё в советские времена, в 80-е годы. А тогда литература проходила строгий контроль. Тем более детская. Допустили же её как-то, издали. Значит, приняли решение, что можно детям подобное читать. Я, правда, несколько лет назад, просмотрев книгу, удивился :-) . И принял другое решение :-). Пока ребёнку не показывать.

А удивился потому, что читал когда-то эти сказки, и тогда на меня подобные эпизоды **особо плохого** впечатления не производили.

Comment: Ребёнок иногда может бояться другого, не того, что взрослые. У Кира Булычева, в какой-то из повестей про Алису Селезнёву, было написано, что дети могут не испугаться вооружённых бандитов, но бояться зайти в тёмную комнату.

Comment: Это точно! Моя старшая в возрасте 2-х лет боялась ... клоунов! Хотя никто ее ими не пугал. 
    А про темноту анекдот.
- Доктор! Я боюсь стоматологов и темноты!
- Ну, стоматологов - это понятно. А почему темноты?
- А кто его знает, сколько в этой темноте стоматологов?
 P.s. Готовлюсь к булыжникам в свой огород. Не получается диалог в столбик записать.

Comment: >Не получается диалог в столбик записать.

Здесь, на этом форуме, разметка текста какая-то особенная. И другие правила пользования тоже. Сам некоторое время не мог разобраться. Писать с новой строки -- 2 раза нажать клавишу "Энтер".

Comment: Надюшка, мне 38 лет, но я до сих пор их боюсь)))) Ну, не то, чтобы боюсь, но уж смешными они мне точно не кажутся. Какими-то уродами с искаженными лицами, под которыми может прятаться что угодно)))))  
Nikolja, это особенности ХэшКода. К ним просто надо приноровиться, а потом автоматически получается.)))

Comment: Я тоже к клоунам отношусь натороженно. Особого восторга не испытываю. Хотя в этом году в цирке клоуны понравились. Они были с  "легким макияжем" и хорошими шутками (большая редкость!)